# dnspython 2.1 xfr zone transfer

Tags: python, dnspython

I used to use the pieces of code below to obtain the target zone object in the previous dnspython version.

```
name_server = 'oo.abc.com.'
dns_zone = 'xx.abc.com' 
zone = dns.zone.from_xfr(dns.query.xfr(name_server, dns_zone))
```

But *dns.query.xfr()* is deprecated in [dnspython 2.1](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/query.html?highlight=dns.query.xfr()#dns.query.inbound_xfr)

It looks like I need to use *dns.query.inbound_xfr()* instead. But the second argument
*txn_manager* is a *dns.zone.Zone* object. I don't know how to assign this Zone object.

Is there anyone who can tell me how can I get the result *zone* that I get in the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using

```
dns.zone.Zone(dns_zone)
```

and it doesn't work.
Except from the documentation, there is no trace in the sources of `xfr` being deprecated even in 2.2: I assume when it will be, the [example](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/master/examples/xfr.py) will be updated